# Simple multithreading java

Tags: java, multithreading

I've got a inner class in my class doing some asynchronous processing and setting value on parent class. Ex :

```
class Myclass{
   String test;

   public getTestValueFromMyClass(){
      //this starts asynchronous processing on my inner class
   }

   //inner class
   class InnerClass extends TimerTask{
      //doing something asynchronously, when this process is done
      test = "somevalue";
   }
}
```

Now here is the problem from Runner class :

```
class Runner{
    public static void main(String[] args){
       Myclass instance = new Myclass();

       //This is always null because runner class doesn't wait for Inner class to
       //complete asynchronous processing and to set test value
       System.out.println(instance.getTestValueFromMyClass());
    }
}
```

How do I get around this?

Comment: Since you don't appear to be doing anything concurrently, I would use just one thread.  If you want to wait for asynchronous tasks I suggest you use an ExecutorService and Future.get().

Comment: I don't think it will compile.

Comment: yes I was intending to wait for asynchronous task to complete and then to print out the result, but I don't know how

Comment: i would suggest reading one of the thousands of online tutorials on multi-threading in java.  the [oracle one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) is always a good place to start.  google will find you many more...

Comment: FYI dude, I forgot to `threadPool.shutdown();` the pool in my example.    Just edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Others have suggested similar ideas but I'd use a single thread pool with a `Callable`.

Your class that is doing the asynchronous processing should implement `Callable` which will return the computed value.  In this example it returns a `String` but it could also return your own object with more information.

```
public class MyClass implements Callable<String> {
   public String call() {
      //doing something asynchronously, when this process is done
      return "somevalue";
   }
}
```

Your `Runner` class would then create a thread pool, fire off the asynchronous task in the background, and then later wait for it to finish.  When you submit a `Callable` job to the thread-pool, you get a `Future` class back which can be used to wait for the asynchronous job to finish and to get its return value.

```
public class Runner{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       // you can use newFixedThreadPool(...) if you need to submit multiple
       ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
       // you could store this future in a collection if you have multiple
       Future<String> future = threadPool.submit(new MyClass());
       // after submitting the final job, we _must_ shutdown the pool
       threadPool.shutdown();

       // do other stuff in the "foreground" while MyClass runs in the background

       // wait for the background task to complete and gets its return value
       // this can throw an exception if the call() method threw
       String value = future.get();
       System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a similar use case, trying to convert AsyncTasks to ExecutorService to return a List from a Room database. Another answer suggests using submit() on ExecutorService and get() on the Dao method (see stackoverflow.com/questions/52242933/room-database-query). Would appreciate your thoughts on that approach versus the approach using a Callable and a Future.

Answer (score 2):

Evidently, you have to make `getTestValueFromMyClass` to wait for `InnerClass` execution. This can be done with some synchronization facility (Semaphore, CountdownLatch, BlockingQueue...). But most straightforward is to use `java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` instead of `java.util.Timer`. Its method `schedule(Callable<V> callable, long delay, TimeUnit unit)` returns Future, and `Future.get()` waits for and returns the computed value.

Answer (score 2):

One very simple mechanism is to use a `BlockingQueue` to communicate between your threads. Here I am creating the queue in the thread class but it could just as easily be created in the caller and passed to the thread.

```
public class Runner {
  static class MyClass implements Runnable {
    // Thread will post to this queue when it completes.
    BlockingQueue q = new ArrayBlockingQueue(1);

    // Call to wait for the post.
    public void waitForFinish() throws InterruptedException {
      // Just take! This will wait until something gets posted.
      q.take();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
      try {
        // Just wait ten seconds.
        Thread.sleep(10000);
      } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        // Just exit when interrupted.
      } finally {
        try {
          // Signal finished.
          q.put("Done");
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
          // Just exit when interrupted.
        }
      }
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    // Make my instance.
    MyClass instance = new MyClass();
    // Fire it off.
    new Thread(instance).start();
    // Wait for it to finish.
    instance.waitForFinish();
    // All done.
    System.out.println("Finished");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a handler and post a message when processing is done!

Comment: thank you for your response, do you have example/link, something similar I don't really know what you're talking about

Comment: sorry, my suggestion was intended for Android developing.You don't need a thread for this. But if you insist in having a separate thread, then just call a method when you are ready with processing!

Answer (score 0):

```
class Myclass{
   // pre initialize thread pool
   private static ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 5 );

   private String test;

   public String getTestValueFromMyClass() throws Exception {
      // start asynchronous calculations
      Future<String> resultHandler = 
           executor.submit( new Callable<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public String call() throws Exception {
                        return "Asynchronously calculated result";
                    }
                } );
      // do something in current thread
      // ...
      // wait until asynchronous task ends, get result 
      // and assign it to instance variable
      this.test = resultHandler.get();

      return test; // returns string "Asynchronously calculated result"
   }
}
```

Comment: this returns string Asynchronously calculated result, but my program is still running, why doesn't it end ?

Comment: Because `resultHandler.get()` waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves result (also there is version of `get` with timeout): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get%28%29